# The use for attr function in R

Tags: r, attr

It might be a stupid question but I couldn't figure out the purpose of attr function in R

```
Obj <- list(l=5.2, m= matrix(0,3,2),g = c(3,4,5),h = matrix(1,5,3))
```

I though by writing

```
l <- attr(Obj, "l") # will return the 5.2 and 
m <- attr(Obj,'m') # will return the matrix m etc..
```

but when do that i get NULL.

I need to know what I am missing in here and am I using the attr function in right way?

Also if possible what is the different between attr and attributes functions

Thank you

Comment: If you haven't read the help files `?attr` & `?attributes`, those may be good places to start. The objects in a list aren't the list's attributes.

Comment: Using your code, see, for instance, `attributes(Obj$m)`. A matrix is a vector with a `dim` attribute.

Comment: @Z.Lin I read the document but they are not clear to me and @ Rui Barradas using your code only works to get the dims of the matrix but if you use attributes(Obj$l) i still get NULL. Thanks

Comment: Obj$l is not an attribute.  If you want to make l an attribute take it out of the list and assign it using `attr(Obj, l) <- 5.2`.

Comment: @Elin Thank Elin, but what is the purpose of attr then?

Comment: For example, in dplyr::group_by there is an attribute that gives the grouping variables.  The class of an object is an attribute. The dimension names.  Attributes basically describe the object but are not part of the object.  So you can have the same object but different dimnames.   It's the difference between `==` and `identical()`.